# My script in autostart not work correctly

Tags: raspbian, boot, script

I am very new in linux and I don't know where I make mistake.
I am using Raspbian. When I manually start script **press.sh** everything works fine. But when I start this script from /etc/rc.local it not works correctly.

Content of press.sh with explanation

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Press key ..."                #I can't see this
if read -s -t 10 -N 1               #Not wait for 10 sec.
then
    bash /home/monitor.sh
else
    sudo bash /home/pi/video_looper.conf    #This start immediately
fi

touch /run/shm/test             #for test - this works
```

Here is content of rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi


bash /home/press.sh

exit 0
```

Comment: `/home/press.sh` are you sure that path is correct? I would expect you put it in the user'ss home directory, probably `/home/pi/press.sh`

Comment: Yes, path is correct. How you can see in my explanation, **touch /run/shm/test** work ok and **sudo bash /home/pi/video_looper.conf** start immediately. So script run but not work correctly.

Comment: is it just the key press? You don't have any keyboard input available when starting from rc.local. A feature that is well documented. I suggest googling a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

### ANSWER # 1:

In looking at your script, I see a potential issue in the use of `sudo`. You may get away with this in Raspbian, but you won't in many other distributions (distros). This is due to the fact that a `sudo` typically demands authentication, and if you're running this at startup, you won't see the prompt.

The meaning of your comments in the script are not clear to me; e.g. "#I can't see this" - huh???

Also - the location of your script: `/home/monitor.sh`?!?! I don't think you should put a script in `/home`! Put it in `/home/pi` instead.

In your `rc.local` file you have: `bash /home/press.sh`

1. You've got a shebang in your script: `#!/bin/bash` that specifies `bash`. I don't believe you need it again in front of your script name.
2. You've specified the location of your script in `/home/press.sh`     Really? Is that where it is? or, is it in `/home/pi/press.sh`?

### ANSWER # 2:

I don't think placing your startup script in `rc.local` is your best move. I'm not saying it can't be made to work, but it may be more difficult than it need be. [This page from the "official" documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) says (more or less) the same thing.

`rc.local` usage is now being deprecated in all Linux distributions in favor of `systemd` - a more rational, reliable and predictable approach. If you're just starting in Linux, I don't feel you'll be handicapped if you **never** learn to use `rc.local`. Here are some good references on `systemd`: [1](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2832405/what-is-systemd-and-why-does-it-matter-to-linux-users.html), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), [3](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).

Don't be intimidated by all of this documentation - learning is a *process*, so proceed at your own pace. But learning comes from *doing* more than reading, so I'd encourage you to read a little, try a little, read a little more, etc, etc.

### ANSWER # 3:

In the meantime, there is a third alternative to starting your script at boot time: `cron`. It is much easier to use than `rc.local` or `systemd`, and you should be able to get your script running with very little research. I will assume that you are running as user `pi`, and that you can get away with using `sudo` in a script without authentication. Here's the approach in a nutshell:

1. From the command line as user `pi`, enter the following:

```bsh
export EDITOR=/bin/nano
crontab -e
```

2. You may be prompted at this point to choose an *editor*. I'd recommend sticking with an editor named [`nano`](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/). If you don't wish to use `nano`, choose an editor, and designate it in the `export` line above.
3. When your (pi's) `crontab` is opened, add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```bsh
@reboot (/bin/sleep 30; /home/pi/press.sh >> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

Let's break this down:

- `@reboot` tells `crond` to run this job at boot time
- `/bin/sleep 30` => waits 30 seconds before launching `press.sh`; gives the system time to gather all resources needed (networking, etc)
- `/home/pi/press.sh` => launches your script
- `>> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1` redirects all output (incl `stderr` (aka `2`)) to a file - so you can see what happened!

Try this. If it doesn't work, edit your question to include some details & we'll help you troubleshoot.

### ANSWER # 4:

As a new Linux & RPi user, one of the first things you should practice is using the documentation. However, this is a bit of an art because:

- documentation and software aren't always *in sync*,
- because different Linux distros do things differently,
- and because, well - some people are a bit sloppy when it comes to documentation.

But the only way to overcome this is through experience. Everyone needs help from time to time - don't hesitate to ask for it. BUT: Make an effort to help yourself FIRST.

I feel the first stop in documentation is the system manuals; e.g. `man crontab` (from the command line, btw) would be a reasonable first step in this case. You can even check out `man man` to learn about the system manuals! You may not get all of your questions answered there, but you'll be able to ask more intelligent questions!

Comment: Tnx @Seamus for detailed answer. I put all my files in /home/pi/. I tryed this option with cronjob but result is same - **video_looper.conf** start immediately. In cronjoblog I get **Press key ...**. I tryed to put in press.sh only **echo "Press key ..."** but when I reboot I get only command line. There is no **Press key ...**. Maybe is problem with configuration of this program **video_looper** ( github.com/adafruit/pi_video_looper ). For note, if I not put sudo bash in press.sh, video_looper won't start.

Comment: @Zlatko: Here's the thing: `cron` jobs are not intended to be interactive. Is this "Press key" input you're missing something that can be decided beforehand? Why are you running this at boot time? If you need for the program to wait for an indeterminate period of time, you can do that, but the prompt is currently going into the log file because of the `>> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1` specification. Please explain what it is you want to do & we'll try to help.

Comment: I have this video_looper and I want possibility to setup display orientation (portrait or landscape).

Comment: @Zlatko: Let me see if I understand this: You've got your script started - correct? And this "Press key..." business is to set portrait vs landscape orientation **after** the video looper starts playing? What is it that prevents you from deciding on portrait vs landscape BEFORE you boot? Sorry - I'm not a mind-reader. If you want help, you need to describe what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Zlatko: I still don't understand your use case, but I had a thought that might help: You may want to look into using an [`expect` script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for your application. Here's a [reasonable example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35328_01/E35336/html/vmcli-script.html), and you can find lots more for the price of an Internet search :)

Comment: I want that user can choice, before video_looper start, between portrait and landscape orientation. When I manually start press.sh it call another bash where I can press 1 for landscape and 2 for portrait. After that, raspberry reboot and if I don't press any key, video_looper start. I spend three days on internet search but without success.

Comment: This is my first contact with linux (I working with it only few days, I have some experience in C++), but anyway I wrote script in Python (for the first time) for downloading files from internet, check if this files exist on SD card, deleting unnecessarily files etc. But with this Press key ... I stuck. I will check for this expect script.   P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: One more thing that may be important. I don't know how, but video_looper start skipping username and password.

Comment: Can it not run without `sudo`?

Comment: You mean **sudo bash /home/pi/video_looper.conf**? If there is no sudo it will not start.